# NodeJS String.replace() problem while filtering

Tags: node.js, json, filtering

I can't modify the filtering parameter with

*String.replace()*

I can get the filtering keys from the URL as an object but its badly fromatted from me.

Filtering: {{URL}}/api/v1/bootcamps?averageCost[lt]=10000

*Current format:*  { averageCost: { lt: '10000' } }

*Right fromat:* { averageCost: { $lt: '10000' } }

So I tried to convert it as a String and replace that value. But that value can be: *lt, lte, gt, gte, in* but it has some problem because the line after the *.replace()* method doesnt executed and of course the catch block cathes the error...

My code snippet:

```
try {
        console.log(req.query);
        const queryStr = JSON.stringify(req.query);
        console.log(queryStr); //thats the last thing I get
        queryStr = queryStr.replace(
            /\b(gt|gte|lt|lte|in)\b/g,
            match => `$${match}`
        );
        console.log(queryStr); // I dont get this

        const bootcamps = await Bootcamp.find();

        res.status(200).json({
            succes: true,
            count: bootcamps.length,
            data: bootcamps
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(404).json({ succes: false });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace it correctly you should use something like this:

```
let queryStr = '{ "averageCost": { "lt": "10000" }, "test": { "gt": "12345"} }';
const regex = /\b(gt|gte|lt|lte|in)\b/g;
queryStr = queryStr.replace(regex, '$$' + "$1"); // <-- here is the correct replace
```

This will replace `queryStr` with:

```
{ "averageCost": { "$lt": "10000" }, "test": { "$gt": "12345"} }
```

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c52z8ewr/

If you need the object back just do `JSON.parse(queryStr)`

Comment: Thanks for the help!. It still doesnt work, but at least I moved a step further. The problem is your *queryStr* looks like this: *"{ averageCost: { lt: '10000' } }";*

But when I run the 
*const queryStr = JSON.stringify(req.query);*
line, and log it, it looks like this:
*{"averageCost":{"lt":"10000"}}*.... So thats why it doesnt work... How could I solve this?

Comment: Do you need the JS object returned instead a string? Just do `JSON.parse(queryStr)` after you replaced it

Comment: Yes, I need it as an object but first I need to replace the *lt* for example to *$lt*

Comment: So it works in this format: * "{ averageCost: { lt: '10000' } }"*, but mine is  looks like this(after the stringify): *{"averageCost":{"lt":"10000"}}*

Comment: That's not a problem look at the answer it works as is

Answer (score 0):

You can also Try This

```
const queryCpy = { ...this.query };

    // console.log(queryCpy, 'before filter');


    console.log(queryCpy, 'after filter');

    let queryString = JSON.stringify(queryCpy);

    queryString = queryString.replace(
        /\b(gt|gte|lt|lte)\b/g,
        (rep) => `$${rep}`,
    );

    console.log(queryString, 'after filter');
```

Answer (score 0):

If want an object in return do:

```
const bootcamps = await Bootcamp.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the Same issue and solved it in the craziest possible way

in your code use ('$' + match) instead of (`$${match}`).
So the code will be like:

```js
queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gte|gt|lte|lt)\b/g, (match) => {
  return '$' + match;
});
```